# The importance of a state without a prior state?

Tags: epistemology, ontology

Does the existence of a state with no prior time throw models we use for explaining the existing universe for a loop? Or does it even matter?

Comment: prior to 'big bang' or prior to state collapse?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what either would mean, please answer both with each assuming either direction please. I was intending however the big bang.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little confusing. You cannot have a state without time - a state evolves *in time*.

When a measurement occurs this provokes a collapse in the state through decoherence with the environment it then continues to evolve. Note a measurement is defined to be anything that actually causes a collapse, it doesn't ahve to be a specific measuring device operated by some conscious being.

Hence, at least when physically modelled, there is no prior state.

However one can speculate at what happens at the Big Bang. Since spacetime is held to have started then, a prior state again isn't possible - there is literally no spacetime in which it can occur.

There may be other cosmologies which allows spacetime to continue through this 'singularity'. One could argue since the physical world is uncomfortable with infinite anything, this is only an *apparent* singularity and spacetime does continue through it. In which case the state should also continue through this singularity. But this isn't mainstream.

So, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: "a state evolves in time."  Not necessarily.  See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture

Comment: "Since spacetime is held to have started then".  I don't think that's correct either.  See, for example:  *I’ve written about this many times before, of course, including a great introduction to the Big Bang for beginners, and a couple of lengthy explanations that the Big Bang isn’t, in fact, the beginning of the Universe*.  http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2013/06/12/what-is-the-big-bang-all-about/

Comment: In the Wheeler-DeWitt equation for canonical QG, the entire concept of time is absent altogether. Temporal evolution as we normally conceive of it is nothing more than a local gauge transformation on the state vector.

Comment: @DavidH: If you look at the wikipedia article on [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93DeWitt_equation) equation you'll note that time is implicit in the equation - it requires decoherence & clock operators to make it explicit. Perhaps an analogy makes this clearer - spacetime in GR is not time+space, as minkowski said space & time disappear into this 4-d concept, it requires taking coordinates to make it explicit again.

Comment: There is no global evolution in the Hamiltonian because what is labelled by time no longer signifies time: It is the kernel of the Hamiltonian that is Physical. Your assertion that there is *no time* is only one point in a spectrum of possibilities. Its generally known as the problem of time.

Comment: The [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-gravity/#5.1) says this: "One can ask whether the problem of time arising from the canonical program tells us something deep and important about the nature of time. Julian Barbour...thinks that it tells us that time is illusory...However, it can also be argued (Weinstein) that the super-Hamiltonian itself should not be expected to generate time-evolution; rather, one or more “true” Hamiltonians should play this role. (Butterfield, Isham, Rovelli)"

Comment: It also goes on to say "...time looks strange in this context because the formalism is attempting to capture the dynamics of general relativity...[the problem of time] resurfaces in arguably the most covariant of approaches, the Feynman path-integral approach. In this case that central task is to compute the amplitude for going from an initial state to a final state...However, one cannot get around the fact that general relativity is a theory with gauge freedom, and so whenever one has diffeomorphic initial and final hypersurfaces, the propagator will be trivial, and there will be no change".

Comment: I don't know enough canonical QG'ists to make a poll - but going by the SEP article - the dominant view is leaning towards *not* interpreting time as illusory but real.

Comment: @Centauri: If you read what I said *carefully* I do mention that - in 'other cosmologies'. Yes, it is true that the Heisenberg Picture has time independent states but its Observables are *time-dependent*. The Heisenberg picture & Schrodinger picture (which is the one I used in my answer as the OP is asking about time-dependent states) differ by a rotation. They're essentially the same picture and its a matter of choosing coordinates here.

Comment: One could argue for a picture that doesn't involve a choice of basis - and I'm sure that there is one and probably invented by physically inclined mathematicians; but real Physicists are prone to choosing coordinates...

Comment: Not only does this answer help clarify what I was asking in the sense before I didn't know the Quantum mechanical definition of state (could have looked it up I guess) but I think you and the rest of SE that answered explained the decoherence concept well enough. Also I can't quite conceptualize the meaning of this long debate quite yet, so if Mozibur and Alfred or David and/or some other informed third party would help me understand the reason and the relevant information behind the time / implicit time arguments that wouldbe appreciated. I will make a new question upon suggestion if need be.